# How to deep copy an object in Realm containing a RealmList as a property and not have the RealmList objects referencing the same object

Tags: android, copy, realm

I have 3 Realm Objects

```
public class Portfolio extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public RealmList<PortfolioCoin> portfolioCoins = new RealmList<>();
}

public class PortfolioCoin extends RealmObject {
    public Coin coin;
    public RealmList<Holdings> holdings = new RealmList<>();
    public int color;
}

public class Holdings extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public double amount;
    public double price;
}
```

Now i would like my users to be able to duplicate their portfolios. 
If i create a new portfolio and do this

```
portfolio.portfolioCoins.addAll(activePortfolio2.portfolioCoins);
```

Both portfolios are basically referencing the same objects. How do i do a deep copy of the items in the list, remembering that its nested twice. Holdings is nested in PortfolioCoin, and PortfolioCoin is nested in Portfolio.

Do i really have to write nested loops to do this? and itereate over each item and then iterate over each item within each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following trick

```
portfolio.portfolioCoins.addAll(realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(realm.copyFromRealm(activePortfolio2.portfolioCoins, 2))); // maybe 3?
```

Comment: it works for PortfolioCoin items but the Holdings items are still linked. If i delete a holding from a PortfolioCoin on one Portfolio it deletes from both Portfolios. I can however delete PortfolioCoins from one without affecting the other so this is at least a step forward

Comment: If you don't want to obtain the linked Holdings, then specify copyFromRealm with `1`

Comment: Ah i see the dilema.. My Holdings has a primary key on id so thats why they always linked. Should be a seperate question but is it possible to copy a list in realm giving all items a new unique long id?

Comment: When you do `realm.copyFromRealm()`, everything is detached, do if you iterate the unmanaged list and assign a new ID for each object, then `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate()` will insert them as new elements in the db.